# How to Use GitLab CI/CD Variables in pytest.ini File?

Tags: python, gitlab, pytest, cicd

I'm working on setting up tests for my project using pytest in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline. I have some configuration options that I would like to parameterize in the pytest.ini file using variables defined in my GitLab CI/CD pipeline like **$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG**.

However, when I try to reference these GitLab CI/CD variables in the pytest.ini file using the ${CI_VARIABLE_NAME} syntax, they are not being replaced with their actual values during test execution.

- pytest.ini

  ```
   [pytest]
   env =
       branch_name = feature-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  ```

Could someone please provide guidance on how to correctly use GitLab CI/CD variables in the pytest.ini file? Is there a specific syntax or configuration required to make this work? or is there any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at the README.md of the pytest plugin you are referencing: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-env and I see under "transformation":

> **Transformation**
>
> You can use existing environment variables using a
> python-like format, these environment variables will be expended
> before setting the environment variable:
>
> ```
> [pytest]
>
> env =
>    RUN_PATH=/run/path/{USER}
> ```

So in your pytest.ini file, remove the `$` sign before the curly brackets.

I would also advise you to use [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/4.12.1/) in combination with `pytest` and .gitlab-ci.yml

`tox` allows you to run tests in isolated environments with different versions of python for example, and you can use it in combination with gitlab CI/CD environment variables.